# Deploying published ASP Core app onto Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: dnx, windows-10-iot-core

I have published my app on my x64 developer machine using the following command,

```
dnu publish --out C:\myapp\ --no-source --runtime dnx-coreclr-win-arm.1.0.0-rc1-final
```

It publishes fine and I can see the correct runtime in the folder.  Now I've copied it onto a USB stick and put that into the Pi then attempted to run it using the kestrel command, which is what I use on all other platforms.

Unfortunately all I get is,

```
Failed to locate or load coreclr.dll
```

Even if I try and run dnx from within the runtime folder, I get the same error.  I'm assuming that I've missed something here.  I didn't think I had to install dnx on the target machine also, doesn't it just run from the folder?

Nick.

Comment: Seems like it may be related to this https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3095  and mean that rc1-final is broken.  But i'll keep looking around.

Comment: So a summary from the GitHub issue, some have suggested using coreclr.dll from the latest RC2 build, this didn't work for me.  I also tried targeting my app to so that I can use the entire runtime, but my app won't run on the latest RC2 build, it isn't quite ready yet.